# Can Sarada Uchiha activate the rinnegan?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden, boruto

Sarada Uchiha is the daughter of Sasuke and Sakura. Sasuke has Karin's Chakra (through Uzumaki blood line, being the descendants of Asura Ōtsutsuki) too, since he had used her ability to heal himself by drinking her blood.

The fact that Karin wore glasses and the fact that Sarada needs to wear glasses, may be a hints to this.

My question is, if Sarada possess Indra's and Asura's Chakra, can she awaken the Rinnegan, as the way Sasuke had did?

Comment: It could be possible.

Comment: This is a future event - nothing's been proven whether or not she can, so I'm electing to close this.  We can't answer this with any credible source backing us up; we're subject to speculation.

Comment: If she has both the chakra, then yes, Rinnegan will be activated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking about something that hasn't been revealed yet. This isn't an "event," as intended by the close reason, which is talking about anime production. This is an in-universe question and is on-topic. While there may not be an affirmative answer, doesn't mean the question can't exist. We have lots of questions as such.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade: if you can provide a source that answers key assumptions of this question - namely whether or now Sarada has the right chakra, then I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: The requirement is to possess both indra's and ashura's chakra. But still, it cannot be confirmed that she'll activate it just because of possessing both ashura's and indra's chakra since even Madara (who is the reincarnation of Indra) took years to activate rinnegan with Hashirama's (reincarnation of Ashura) cells.

Comment: Not knowing the Naruto license, I would rather close this question as "primarely opinion-based" as it is a "what if?" question

Comment: @Makoto All though phrased a tad awkwardly, and based upon a misconception, the question is perfectly answerable with the current in-universe resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sasuke has Karin's Chakra (through Uzumaki blood line, being the descendants of Asura Ōtsutsuki) too, since he had used her ability to heal himself by drinking her blood.

First of all I would like to correct this misconception. Sasuke obtained his rinnegan powers After receiving half of Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki's chakra, not by drinking the blood of karin.

Ninjutsu haven't been shown to have any form of lingering chakra effects, making it highly unlikely this one would have had. The chakra would likely be used up immediately to heal said critical wounds.

Now coming back to your original question

> My question is, if Sarada possess Indra's and Asura's Chakra, can she awaken the Rinnegan, as the way Sasuke had did?

Yes, if she has both types of chakra, which is highly likely due to Sasuke having both, she could. But not in the same way as Sasuke did, as this would require Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki's to sacrfice his chakra to her.

However the likelihood she will active the rinnegan is close to non, as this would require larger amounts of Asura and Indra's chakra. Which even took Madara decades while actively producing the chakra through DNA infusion.

Comment: So you are saying Sarada Uchiha wearing glasses similar to Karin Uzumaki is a coincidence, I guess my theory is too wayward. I got this doubt because of the boruto movie. Thanks!

Comment: @NarenMurali Blood does bring dna. Dna does play a role in physical features. That might be related to that part, but that has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have just answeared similar theme on different question, so basically yes, Sarada and basically anyone can manifest rinnegan, here is the explaination:

Okay, let me introduce my personal opinion on this: Otsutsuki have gained the power of charka, which made them manifest the origin chakra eye technique. But as the time went by, the technique was weaker and weaker and thus was actually so weak compared to the predecessor it became a new one, lets consider this one a Rinnesharingan, but as we know, somewhere had to be the moment, which leaded to manifestation of the new technique, so if we would step back (merge the pathes that did split) we would acquire the technique, so basically, any eye, just a little bit related to the origin can be rinnegan and thus even Narutos current eye potentionaly could handle rinnegan, which it didnt. Anyway, any time you merge the pathes that have split, you will gain its predecessors power.

Edit: As I have discussed with my friend, I want to notice Im not saying that your surely will get the exact eye, this is still a new eye and a new evolution, so the eye will be different, but most likely the changes are gonna be sooo unnoticable, that you can consider it a fully flaged predecessor